# Applets, HTTPS and Windows Domain

Tags: java, windows, security, https, applet

I'm experiencing a trouble with Applet authentication over HTTPS.
It seems that when I try to log in using Windows authentication account,
like ***domain* \ *username***, applet will remove the ***domain*** and authentication fails.
LDAP is configured properly because IIS autentication works.

Is it normal?
Is there any check that I can do?

Comment: *"Suggestion?"*  Sentences.

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand ...

Comment: Write entire sentences.  Ask a *specific* question.